# Docker run stops on RUN npm install

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and just trying to create a simple node.js app image with following Dockerfile:

```
 FROM node 
 WORKDIR /app 
 COPY . . 
 EXPOSE 3000 
 RUN npm install 
 CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

When I run "docker build ." the image does not get created but also no errors are thrown:

```
[+] Building 4.4s (7/8)
[internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                        
transferring dockerfile: 142B                                                                                                                                                                                        
[internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                           
transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                             
[internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest                                                                                                                                                              
[1/4] FROM 
docker.io/library/node@sha256:543c034446e58fb3991842e22db7a404f5feb1050cf6126cb551e03cae0e7ac1                                                                                                               
resolve 
[internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                           
transferring context: 90.96kB                                                                                                                                                                                         
CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /app 
[3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                               
[4/4] RUN npm install
```

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them

Docker image shows no images. I'm running Windows 10, all app files as well as package*.json are located in the same directory as the Dockerfile.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: IIUC `npm install` looks for `package.json` to determine what to install. Please add the `package.json`

Comment: A good practice is to use `ENTRYPOINT` rather than `CMD`. There are nuances but `ENTRYPOINT` makes the image's containers behave similarly to the process it runs. In this case, your container likely should always run `node app.js` and replacing `CMD` with `ENTRYPOINT` will do this. If you use `CMD` and run your container with any arguments (even if inadvertently), you'll override the `CMD` (i.e. `node app.js`) and it will break.

Comment: Adding "COPY package*.json ./" helped, thanks!